# Android Studio local variable says Unreachable statement Error

Tags: java, android, variables, drop-down-menu

So i have a problem with my local variable it says Unreachable statement.
This is the line of code i get the error (" View textViewOptions; ") i cant even run the app

```
    private View findViewById(int position) {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
    return view;


View textViewOptions;
    textViewOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ViewHolder holder;


    public void onClick(View view) {

        //creating a popup menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.textViewOptions);
        //inflating menu from xml resource
        popup.inflate(R.menu.chatmenu);
        //adding click listener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.BlockUser:
                        //handle menu1 click
                        return true;
                    case R.id.MuteNotificationsCH:
                        //handle menu2 click
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        popup.show();

    }
});
}
```

Comment: why would it be available if the line above that is `return view;`?

Comment: Put `return view` at the very bottom of the method. `return` ends the method execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in commnets, return keyword is used to exit the method. From there onwards execution will stop. So the code below return statement will not be executed and hence will become unreachable.

So put `return view;` as the last statement of the method